# How to publish or deploy from tfs to my server

Tags: tfs, web-deployment, publishing

I want to build and publish from tfs to my server

I am getting error at publish time
Unable to associate artifact with resource at location:C:\agent_work\

Comment: We need more details to help you.  What version of TFS? What are you deploying?  How did you setup the deployment?   Screenshots would probably help as well.

Comment: What version of TFS?
I have latest TFS version

What are you deploying?
I want to deploy my web app

How did you setup the deployment?
1) I have create one build with below task list
 Visual studio build
 Visual Studio Test
 Copy Fiels
 Publish Build Artifacts
 Nuget Installer

Sorry for, I don't know how to attach screen in StackOverflow...

Thanks for replay.....

Comment: Please attach the whole log.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, your build template should look like:

[image]

The error message "Unable to associate artifact with resource at location:C:\agent_work\" means you choose **File share** and specify the **Path** as "*C:\agent_work*" in **Publish Build Artifacts** step, correct?

**Solution:**

If you use a file share, you need to specify the **UNC file path** to the folder. Try to use `\\my\share` in Path item instead of a absolute path C:\agent_work.